# Standard way of mapping EDI data in Cloud based application

Tags: mapping, edi, smooks

Hi I am working with Cloud based application and I am researching on various ways of Mapping Electronic Data Interchange. In my scenario I have to map two external application attributes suppose:

Application 1 :
firstName , 
lastName

Application 2 :
fname , 
lname

The one way i am doing is mapping the attributes in the XML like this :

`<App>
<firstName>fname</firstName>
<lastName>lname<lastName>
</App>`

Here I am assigning the attributes of first application with the attributes of second application.

I am looking for the optimize and best practises for mapping the attributes of two application.

I am also looking for the convenient way of storing the mapping data in to XML, JSON which one is more convenient and flexible and take less time in conversion programming.